# CSS margins not collapsing

Tags: css, margin

I have created some simple media objects and stacked them horizontally.
I have added 5px of margin, but the space between them looks 10px.
Why are the margins not collapsing?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  float: left;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  width: calc(80% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <aside></aside>
  <main></main>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/rules-of-margin-collapse/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS margin collapsing **only** occurs vertically & under 3 circumstances:

> **Adjacent siblings:** The margins of adjacent siblings are collapsed (except when the later sibling needs to be cleared past floats). For example:

```
<p>The bottom margin of this paragraph is collapsed...</p>
<p>...with the top margin of this paragraph.</p>
```

> **Parent and first/last child:** If there is no border, padding, inline content, block_formatting_context created or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.
>
> **Empty blocks:** If there is no border, padding, inline content, height, or min-height to separate a block's margin-top from its margin-bottom, then its top and bottom margins collapse.

Take a look at [Margin Collapsing here in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

In your case they won't collapse, you'd better applying margin to only one side excluding last item in the row:

```
aside {
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

aside.last {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Margins only collapse vertically, not horizontally. You have `5px` of margin on **all sides** of `<aside>` and `<main>` so there **should be** `10px` of space.

`<aside> left margin + <main> right margin = 10px`

Oh, and margins (vertical ones) don't collapse for floated elements.